# Dao class not fount Exception in Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a problem with spring-beans.xml

this is the problem:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [DAO.UsersaosiImplDatabase] for bean with name 'UsersaosiDAO' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-beans.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DAO.UsersaosiImplDatabase
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1277)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:842)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:416)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:192)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DAO.UsersaosiImplDatabase
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:258)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinition.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanDefinition.java:408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doResolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.resolveBeanClass(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1200)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: DAO.UsersaosiImplDatabase is not in the CLASSPATH.  Check the WEB-INF/classes/DAO for UsersaosiImplDatabase.class and WEB-INF/lib for a JAR containing that .class file.

Comment: i can't find WEB-INF/classes/DAO  any adeas ??

Comment: Yes, compile the .java source into .class files and package your app into a proper WAR.

Comment: ok tnx the probleme was fixed it's probleme of JAR